# Get rid of Horizontal Scrollbar on SharePoint Online Public Website?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, css

On my out of the box public website have a horizontal scrollbar I can't find the source of. No matter how I try to find it's origin, I'm having trouble getting rid of it. It may be an error in the Oslo CSS file or some JavaScript rendering issue. But I havn't found it yet.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

Or at least a work around. Set overflow-x to hidden on s4-workspace will "solve" the problem. If you hide overflow in all direction you'd be unable to scroll vertically!

```
#s4-workspace
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Strange that the OOTB content have you a scrollbar! Just a heads up, if your main content is wider than the window size the overflow will be unreachable with this CSS. You can try it yourself by making the width of your browser window smaller. There must be some other element on the page that has a padding or similar that makes it wider than it should :)

Comment: @RobertLindgren True that. That's why this is a "bad" workaround and not a solution of the problem. Still, horizontal scrolling is in any case considered bad UX. So from two evil - my choice is UX first :-)

Comment: You are not Mr UX for nothing ;)